# Where to find Dialogflow javascript function documentation?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I have started learning Dialogflow using the codelabs tutorials provided by Google and am searching for the javascript documentation for dialogflow module.

For example, I have this code:

```html
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug : true});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.close('Welcome to my app!');
});
```

And I want to what functions and stuff the conv object has that is given by the app.intent() handler I created.

I have tried searching on Google's Dialogflow documentation page but am confused, since I am a beginner to all of this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [Dialogflow integration](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/modules/dialogflow.html) from Actions on Google which is designed for Google Assistant. This will work fine with Dialogflow, but something might be different compared to the [Dialogflow Fullfilment library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/libraries/nodejs).

As for the conv object that you are using, you can find it's details in the documentation [here](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.conversation-1.html).